# HTML background music

Tags: html

I have been implementing a page that has background music. I have run into an error. When I first open the page, the music doesn't play. I have to reload it multiple times to get it to work. I tried changing it to an iframe but it still doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
<embed src='background_music.mp3' hidden='true' border='0' autostart='true' loop='true'>
```

I am using a Chromebook.

Comment: Seems to work for me. what browser are you using?

Comment: The chrome browser

Comment: Some browsers prevent non-muted autoplay, if you are not interacting with the page first. Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes
Firefox: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/02/firefox-66-to-block-automatically-playing-audible-video-and-audio/

Comment: Perhaps it take time to download the file?

Comment: else you can try with html5 audio instead: https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_audio_autoplay.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed

> Keep in mind that most modern browsers have deprecated and removed
>   support for browser plug-ins, so relying upon  is generally not
>   wise if you want your site to be operable on the average user's
>   browser.

Like someone suggested in another answer, you should use `<audio>`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio